# How do I make header and sidebar stay?

Tags: php, html

This is my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
   <?php
    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/sidebar.php');
    include('includes/content.php');
    include('includes/footer.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is code for my sidebar.php

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="index.php" class="sidebar">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="flower.php" class="sidebar">flower</a></li>
    <li><a href="study.php" class="sidebar">Study</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendar.php" class="sidebar">Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="diary.php" class="sidebar">Diary</a></li>
</ul>
```

if I click flower, it will go to flower.php. I didn't include header, sidebar, and footer, and found that it shows only contents of flower.php, not showing header, sidebar, and footer. Is there any way to make it showing? Or should I just write down all the code below again?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
   <?php
    include('includes/header.php');
    include('includes/sidebar.php');
    include('includes/content.php');
    include('includes/footer.php');
```

Comment: how about using links like `<a href="?page=flower"` and selecting the included content based on that parameter? there are plenty of examples around, as well as examples on how to use mod_rewrite to make the urls nicer.

Comment: Maybe you should use php forms and include it all in the same file.

Comment: AJAX content injection? Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your header, footer and sidebar on each of your page, because it won't create any problem because if you need to make change you would only change in required file and the change will occur in all other files as well. While content.php you should have your specific code for each page separately.
Hope this help